# Error in warbler Installation

Tags: ruby, rvm, warbler, ruby-2.1

I have installed ruby 2.1.1 using

```
 \curl -L https://get.rvm.io |    bash -s stable --ruby --autolibs=enable --auto-dotfiles
```

the following is my console log

```
dax@administrator:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

dax@administrator:~$ sudo gem install warbler -v=1.3.2
[sudo] password for dax: 
ERROR:  Error installing warbler:
    rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

dax@administrator:~$ rvm use 2.1.1
Using /home/dax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1

dax@administrator:~$ sudo gem install warbler -v=1.3.2
ERROR:  Error installing warbler:
rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
```

although it shows ruby 2.1.1, warbler is not using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `sudo`, this will use the system's `gem` command, which is probably 1.8.7 or so. You'll likely want to `gem install` without `sudo`.

Comment: `gem install warbler -v=1.3.2

Fetching: rubyzip-1.1.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.8 directory.`

Comment: Have you added RVM to your shell config, e.g. `~/.bashrc`? Whats the output of `rvm requirements`?